# Relationship between capacitance & power output

Tags: capacitance

I designed an experiment to test out how voltage affected the power output of a capacitor to a motor. The motor had a rotating component whose RPM I used as a means of quantifying the power output. That said I'm not 100% certain that it is indeed a linear relationship despite what the trendline might suggest. Could someone point me to some relevant equations or perhaps enlighten me as to whether my graph is correct or not?  [image: Voltage plotted against RPM]

Comment: Does the motor speed up very rapidly and then rotate at a constant speed or does the motor speed up gradually and the motor speed in the graph  is the final speed of the motor?

Comment: @Farcher the motor experiences an initial burst of speed then slows down over time, this graph measures the initial burst of speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have written in your comment it appears that the capacitor discharges very rapidly and its stored energy $\frac12 CV^2$ is converted into the rotational kinetic energy of the motor's coil $\frac12I\omega^2$.
$C$ is the capacitance of the capacitor $\rm (F)$, $V$ is the voltage to which the capacitor has been charged $(\rm V)$, $I$ is the moment of inertial of the coil $(\rm kg\, m^{-2})$ and $\omega$ is the angular speed of the coil $(\rm rad\, s^{-1})$.

This might well explain your straight line graph as if $\frac12 CV^2 = \frac12I\omega^2 \Rightarrow V \propto \omega$ which means that a graph of voltage against speed of rotation should be a straight line through the origin.

What is surprising to me is how good your straight line is as I would have expected some of the stored energy in the capacitor to be converted into heat due to the resistance of the coil.

However perhaps your best-fit line is not quite right as the points are not equally distributed about it?
The points at lower rpm are mostly above your best-fit line whilst the points at higher rpm are mostly below your best fit-line.

Comment: I believe this is because excel is taking into account a standard uncertainty and is drawing an average through them.

Comment: Thank you so much though! That really answered my question perfectly